# How to send simple string to a webpage from Android

Tags: android, forms, web, comments, invoke

I have a small problem. I want to somehowe invoke a button in a webpage from an android application and send some information to this page. This is the part of the webpage I want to interact with.

[image: --------]

In this form you write your name, e-mail and a comment. By clicking the button "Изпрати коментар" (which means "Send your comment") you can post a comment in the webpage. So I want to make the same functionallity, but from an android application (to write comments into the webpage).

Does someone of you have any idea how can this be accomplish?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can checkout the HTTP headers and/or parameters that are sent when you send the request. You can imitate the same kind of request in your android app using [HTTPClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)

Comment: you don't send a string to a webpage. at best, you send a request with parameters to a service

Comment: Just show the html source of that page to know the name of the post/get parameters. After that use DefaultHttpClient and HttpPost/HttpGet to mimic sending the form. There are hundreds of examples in this forum.